# Globally declare a hash in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a hash which is present in the main perl script (.pl) I want the hash to be visble to the modules (.pm) that are called in the main perl script. How can I declare it globally? Is it possible?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? But it is already globally visible if you declare it via `our` - you may need to specify namespace to access it (and this is a bad idea).

Comment: It's probably a better idea to pass a reference to that hash to the functions in your modules. Or if the modules are classes, add a reference to that hash to the objects created.

Answer (score 4):

First off - this is a bad idea. Globals or super-globals like you're looking for lead to code with complicated dependencies all over the place - the very thing you're *trying to avoid* by using modules in the first place.

However - you can declare a variable with `our` and then access it via package name.

```
our %thing = ( key => "value" );
print Dumper \%main::thing;
```

This is visible elsewhere in the namespace via full name and module.

(If you really must, you can start mucking around with TYPEGLOBs, but trust me when I say this is a bad idea).

Answer (score 4):

This breaks many rules of good software design, but it's possible using package variables.

In hash.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use MyHashModule;

our %hash = (one => 1, two => 2, three => 3);

say hashkeys();
```

In MyHashModule.pm

```
package MyHashModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw[hashkeys];

sub hashkeys {
  return keys %main::hash;
}

1;
```

But I can't repeat enough what a terrible idea this is. If you were to explain more about what you are actually trying to do, we could probably come up with a solution that is far saner.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended you look to declare local variables as opposed to global variables, whenever possible. If you are only needing to write a small script, there may be no problems with declaring a global variable, but as the script gets bigger, or if you or another developer adds more functionality, there may be some hard to find logic errors that creep in.

That being said, if you must declare a global variable, you would simply change the `my` to `our`, like this:

```
our %global_variable = (key => "value");
```